# Implementation of back() in std::vector

Tags: c++, stl

Why is the Vector back() method implemented in terms of iterators

```
reference back()
{   // return last element of mutable sequence
    return (*(end() - 1));
}
```

rather than something like...

```
return (*(_Myfirst + size()));
```

**Background to this question:**

I have been working recently on optimising some legacy code (an allocator implementation) and noticed that a significant amount of time was being spent in `std::vector::back()`. So I did some experiments using different collections (Vector vs List vs Deque) and since `back()` is basically retrieving the last element in the collection so I also compared `vector::back()` against `vector[size()-1]`

This is the code I used to test:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

int RandomNumber () { return (rand()%100); }



void doVector( std::vector<int>& test_vec )
{
    std::cout << "vect back() = " << test_vec.back() << std::endl;
    {
        boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++ )
            test_vec.back();
    }
}

void doVector2( std::vector<int>& test_vec )
{
    std::cout << "vect [size()-1] = " << test_vec[test_vec.size()-1] << std::endl;
    {
        boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++ )
            test_vec[test_vec.size()-1];
    }

}


void doList( std::vector<int>& test_vec )
{
    std::list<int> test_list(test_vec.begin(),test_vec.end());
    std::cout << "list back() = " << test_list.back() << std::endl;

    {
        boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++ )
            test_list.back();
    }

}

void doDeque( std::vector<int>& test_vec )
{
    std::deque<int> test_deq(test_vec.begin(),test_vec.end());
    std::cout << "Deque back() = " << test_deq.back() << std::endl;

    {
        boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++ )
            test_deq.back();
    }

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> test_vec(100);
    std::generate(test_vec.begin(), test_vec.end(), RandomNumber );

    doVector(test_vec);
    doVector2(test_vec);
    doList(test_vec);
    doDeque(test_vec);
}
```

The results were :

**Removed Results because I had turned on Debug / turned off Optimisations in release times in the order of seconds - I should have seen that**

Clearly I will gain significantly from using vect[ size() - 1] and further to that I will also gain by using vect[0] over front(). I realise that I am tying myself to vector but in the short term that's my chosen direction (Quick win). But, it made me think - why is it that the vector implementations of front() and back() use a less efficient implementation under the hood?

---

vect back() = 41
0.183862s wall, 0.171601s user + 0.000000s system = 0.171601s CPU (93.3%)

vect [size()-1] = 41
0.416969s wall, 0.421203s user + 0.000000s system = 0.421203s CPU (101.0%)

list back() = 41
0.079119s wall, 0.078001s user + 0.000000s system = 0.078001s CPU (98.6%)

Deque back() = 41
0.186574s wall, 0.187201s user + 0.000000s system = 0.187201s CPU (100.3%)

Clearly I was looking at the wrong results when I did my analysis - as this totally backs up the choice of the implementation. Apologies to people who looked at this before this edit.....

Comment: Did you compile this with optimizations enabled, and no debug options?

Comment: Your optimizer must be really bad...with g++-4.7 I can't get it to take more than `0.000001s wall`.

Comment: Actually those results are not - apologies I pasted the wrong ones

Comment: Hard to believe. You do nothing with the acquired back()s so any sane optimizer should optimize the redundant calls out.

Comment: Note that when you write a small separate test rather than using the code in the context of the problem you might get unrelated results. Also note that there are some compiler flags that will greatly affect performance, for example *safe iterators* take a good hit on performance and that is best candidate explanation for why `front()` and `v[0]` might have different performance...

Comment: `return (*(_Myfirst + size()-1));` is going to bypass any iterator checking code.  `*(end()-1)` will run iterator code that checks if it is (say) within bounds.  With reasonable optimizations and with debugging checks gone, I'd expect `*(end()-1)` to resolve to nearly the exact same code as *(end()-1)...

Comment: apologies all bit too quick off the mark on a sunday night - thanks for the replies however.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: Exactly...both `g++` and `clang` understand that `back` has no side-effects, so just drop the whole function (I can't speak for MSVC on this one). If you remove the `std::cout` and `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer` from all the functions, `main` will exit immediately.

Comment: Why do you think that you will gain? Your tests show clearly that back() is faster. I've tried to run it myself and result confirm that back() is faster than [size() - 1]

Comment: i don't - i made the mistake of looking at debug figures and not double checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ specification defines semantics and not implementation. If it matters on an implementation that `std::vector<T, A>::back()` is implemented using a different implementation than the specification suggests, an implementation should just do the Right Thing! Obviously, it needs to still deliver the correct semantics.

The basic reason it is specified as is probably comes from the original implementation: The iterator type of `std::vector<T, A>` was just a `T*` (which is still a valid implementation although one which has become unfashionable for various reason). Contemporary `std::vector<T, A>` implementations tend to use a simple wrapper for pointers.

All that said, the overhead you see should actually be optimized because for decent compilers: What optimization flags did you use?

Comment: Regarding why `T*` as iterator for `std::vector` has become unfashionable, can you elaborate on the reason for that, or do you know anywhere I could read about this?

Comment: Hi Dietmar, yes you're right I spent too long pawing over debug results - but an interesting lesson for me anyway....

Comment: @Paul -- in debug, by having an iterator that isn't a T*, you allow for run-time and compile-time checks on iterator usage (of which there are plenty!).  In release, you can simply either use T* or a class that optimizes down to a T*, and get near-metal performance.  This helps you catch bugs, which seems useful.

Comment: @PaulManta: The primary reason is that the two choices behave slightly different. That is, depending on the iterator type being a pointer or not, the expression `*--v.end()` may or may not compile: If the iterator type actually is a pointer type, this expression is ill-formed (you can't decrement a temporary pointer type). However, if the iterator type is a class, the expression is well-formed. Of course, a [DS9k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:CompuHacker/CHDS9000) implementation would probably choose a pointer type (probably because the DS9k would deliberately make sure you can't guess).

Answer (score 1):

From your question `_Myfirst + size()` I guess you are using `MSVC` that has `iterator` debugging, are you sure that you are using `release` build for your test, since in `debug` build `iterator` debugging take some extra time, but in `release` mode they both take equal time(at least in my machine using `MSVC 2010`)

Answer (score 0):

Because you only get the value and do not use it, the compiler will optimize these codes to no-ops(with -O2).

So the timming is not accurate for comparing the two operation.